# get day month year from java.sql.date

Tags: java

My question is simple my `SQL` query from java returns a date and assign it to a `java.sql.Date` variable.

however i want to get each of the day, month and year as int.  It seems that the methods `getDay()`,`getMonth()` are deprecated.

Are there any other way to achieve this?

what i tried for testing is:

```
String date = "2015-04-12";
java.sql.Date dat = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);
```

now i want year, month and day in an int variable each.

Comment: You should consider to use something like Apache DateUtils or Yodatime (-> Java 8 standard i think), these libraries are able to manage situations like this very good.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
String date = "2015-04-12";
java.sql.Date dat = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);
//create calander instance and get required params
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dat);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: i tried this and as result i got 3 for month. is this normal?

Comment: @Tarounen Yes, months are indexed from `0` in `Calendar` which makes April `3` (it is same value as `Calendar.APRIL` has).

Answer (score 14):

Since `java.sql.Date` extends `java.util.Date` you could use its inherited `toLocalDate()` method to get instance of `LocalDate` (available since Java 8) which supports many `get...()` methods like

```
String date = "2015-04-12";
java.sql.Date dat = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);

LocalDate localDate = dat.toLocalDate();
System.out.println(localDate.getDayOfMonth());
System.out.println(localDate.getMonthValue());
System.out.println(localDate.getYear());
```

Output:

```
12
4
2015
```

Comment: Much easier with toLocalDate(), thank you. This should be the right answer, way better to read then creating a calender instance.